# error when trying to assign value to procedure variable in select using ":="

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have the following stored procedure code:

```
BEGIN
DECLARE procvar INT;
SELECT @uservar := portid();
SELECT procvar := portid();
END
```

I get an syntax error for the second SELECT statement.

So the assignment is allowed for a user session variable (@uservar),  but trying to assign a value to the locally declared variable (procvar) evokes a syntax error.

I cannot find any direct reference to this in the docs on the := operator - all the examples just use @vars. Can anyone explain what is the syntax rule being broken by the second SELECT statement?

Answer (score 2):

Change this `DECLARE XX INT;` to `set @XX = 0;`

Comment: Thanks @reds. I don't think I have made myself clear. The point of the question/code is to show how user session variables are ok (SELECT \@XX:=... works) but variables declared in the procedure are not (SELECT XX:= fails) - I'd like to know why as I can't find any docs on the issue.  I will clarify the question.